# Read windows filename from file in Java

Tags: java, string, file-io

**Background**

For a program I'm writing I need to be able to read Windows filenames from a file. Unfortunately, Windows use `\` instead of `/`, which makes this tricky. I've been trying different ways, but it never seems to work. Here's the Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    static String localFile;
    static String localFilePrefix;
    static String user;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        readConfig("user.txt");
    }

    public static boolean readConfig(String cfgFilePath){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cfgFilePath));
            try{
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    if(line.indexOf("User") != -1){
                        user = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")+1);
                    }else if(line.indexOf("LocalFile") != -1){
                        String tmp = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")+1);
                        System.out.println("Test: " + tmp);
                        setLocalFile(tmp);
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException ee){
                System.err.println(ee.getMessage());
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void setLocalFile(String lFileName){
        System.out.println("FileName: " + lFileName);
        localFile = lFileName;
        if(new File(localFile).isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("Here!");
            localFilePrefix=localFile+File.separator;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the config file:

```
User test
LocalFile C:\User
```

Running this code, whith that file path, doesn't print `Test: C:\Users`,  which it should. Neither does it print `FileName: C:\Users` or `Here!`. If I remove "Users" from the file path, however, it works fine and prints everything it's supposed to. It even recognizes `C:\` as a directory.

**Question**

I don't want the user to be forced to write the file path in a special format just because my program can't handle it. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see any error/exception etc? You need to specify the file at the end as well.

Comment: Sorry, no errors or exceptions as far as I can see. Which makes me even more confused, as Java is good at throwing exceptions. I get an exception if I try parsing it though, I'll add the case to the question.

Comment: So what's the issue then?

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with the error, but in the while loop it should read while((line = reader.readLine()) != null), not `while(line = reader.readLine() != null)`

Comment: The issue is that it seems that it breaks on the while loop for some reason when trying to read e.g. `C:\Users`; the line setting the local variable localFile is never run, which is a pretty big issue.

Comment: @WonderWorld Doesn't work unfortunately; it gives me the error `Incompatible operand types String and int`.

Comment: @Psyberion i meant the extra `()` around the `line = reader.readLine()` , not change null to -1. I changed that in previous comment.

Comment: Perhaps use Path already provided http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: Please show us the complete code needed to reproduce your problem. I tried it, fixed some obvious compile errors and it works fine.

Comment: You have two `try` block and only one `catch`. This code does not compile. Also `(line = reader.readLine() !=null)` is wrong as it should be `((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)`. Please check the posted code.

Comment: @Tobías Sorry about that, missed it when copying. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @Invexity I'll have a look at that, thank you!

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ I'll upload the necessary code, just give me a minute.

Comment: *\ and \U (in data) **mean nothing special**, unless processed by something that cares* (neither `readLine` nor `println` care). They only mean something in a special context, such as string literals. If these character sequences are coming from a file read (which does not treat them special) then the problem is elsewhere. The result of `substring` may be throwing off the results - but not the \ or \U.

Comment: what i know, you can use `/` in path even in windows and java still able to open the file, OR you can use double back slash  `\\\` as path separator in the config file

Comment: also post your config file content

Comment: Provided code (with some compile errors corrections) works fine. Check it  http://ideone.com/XVrhni  Maybe the problem is reading the file and has nothing to do with `/` or `\`. Check if it contains some unexpected non printable characters. Also try adding `ee.printStackTrace();` in the catch block and let us know if there is some error.

Comment: Okej, I've uppdated with code that reproduces the issue when I run it, as well as the contents of the config file. I've also tried clarifying a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first condition `line.indexOf("User") != -1` is `true` for the input `User test` but also for `LocalFile C:\User` (and it will be so for every path that contains `User`). Therefore, the `else if` condition is not evaluated.

Use [`.startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) instead of [`.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-)

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("User")) {
        user = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    } else if (line.startsWith("LocalFile")) {
        String tmp = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        System.out.println("Test: " + tmp);
        setLocalFile(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Jesus, I should've been able to figure that out myself. I feel like an idiot. Anyway, thanks a lot man, you've cured my head ache!